# Getting the number factors of 2 in the given value using recursion

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I'm trying to make a program where a method takes a single positive integer as its argument and returns the number of factors of 2 in the number, an example being numbers that are twice an odd number returns one, numbers that are four times an odd returns two, etc.

```
  public int twos(int n){
    int twos=0;
    if(n%2!=0){
      return(0);
    }
    if(n/3>=1){
      System.out.println("\n"+n);;
     return twos(n/3)+1;
    }
    else{
      return(0);
    }
   // return(twos);
  }
```

The code I have above only works for the integers 6 and 12, but not for all integers. How would you make this work for all digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While creating a recursive implementation, you need always define *Base case* and *Recursive case* (*every recursive method would contain these two parts, either implicitly or explicitly*).

- **Base case** - represents a condition (or group of conditions) under which recursion should terminate. The result for base case is trivial and known in advance. For this task, *Base case* is when the number is not even, return value is `0`.
- **Recursive case** - is the place where the main logic of the recursive method resides and where recursive calls are made. In the *Recursive case* we need to perform a recursive call with `n / 2` passed as an argument, and return the result of this call `+1` (*because the received argument is even, and we need to add one power of `2` to the total count*).

That's how implementation might look like:

```
public int twos(int n) {
    if (n % 2 != 0) return 0; // base case
    
    // recursive case
    return 1 + twos(n / 2);
}
```

Or if you would use a so-called *ternary operator* (*which is an equivalent of* `if-else`) it can be written as:

```
public int twos(int n) {
    return n % 2 != 0 ? 0 : 1 + twos(n / 2);
}
```

*Usage example (in order to be able to call* `twos()` *from the* `main()` *add* `static` *modifier to it):*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(twos(2));
    System.out.println(twos(4));
    System.out.println(twos(12));
    System.out.println(twos(38));
    System.out.println(twos(128));
}
```

*Output:*

```
1   // 2
2   // 4
2   // 12
1   // 38
7   // 128
```